# Windows Phone Hub Layout - where do i put Command buttons?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

So I'm trying to create my first Universal Windows app and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to lay out my hub on the main XAML page.

So I have this:

```
<Hub>
    <HubSection ContentTemplate="{StaticResource BananasList}" />
    <HubSection ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ApplesList}" />
    <HubSection ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CucumbersList}" />
    <HubSection ContentTemplate="{StaticResource OrangesList}" />
</Hub>
```

And that's great, but I want to give the user the ability to "Add" an apple by searching an external web service for all different types of apples and then adding a reference to that apple locally.

Design-wise, how do I lay this out?  Do I put a button and a textbox in the HubSection somehow?  In the header of the HubSection?  Do I just put a "+" link in the header that goes to a separate lookup page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design question? If so, there's no "real" answer, it's all subjective.

A more WP friendly layout is to define an AppBarButton that opens a new page to query your external service, then bring them back to this page after it's done.

---

```
MainPage.xaml

<Page>
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add" Click="NavigateToAddApple"/>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
    <Hub>
        ...
    </Hub>
</Page>
```

---

```
Main.xaml.cs

public void NavigateToAddApple(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(AddApplePage));
}
```

Comment: one thing I wanted to clear up.  There are other hubsections that have vegetables, sports equipment, etc.  Isn't that commandBar shared amongst all the hubsections?  Wouldn't an "add" appbarbutton be confusing?

Comment: The behavior of the button would change depending on what's on the screen, or you show them an intermediate gating screen to choose which of the options they're adding, or your add screen has an option to choose. This is a design question so there's no right answer.